# Are binomial series multiplicative in their bases?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binomial-coefficients, formal-power-series

In $ℚ[Z]$, by $Z \choose k$ denote the polynomial
$${Z \choose k} = \frac{1}{k!}·\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (Z-i),$$
so that ${Z \choose k}(n) = {n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!·(n-k)!}$ in $ℚ$.

Now, in the ring of formal power series $ℚ[Z] [\![ X, Y ]\!]$, define the *binomial series* of $F ∈ (X,Y)$ as
$$(1+F)^Z = \sum_{k=0}^∞ {Z \choose k}F^k.$$
(Or do that specifically for $F = X$, $F = Y$ and $F = X + Y + XY = (1+X)(1+Y) - 1$.)

A natural question is now whether
$$(1+X)^Z(1+Y)^Z = \big((1 + X)(1 + Y)\big)^Z.$$

I believe that to be true, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

$$(1+X)^Z(1+Y)^Z= \sum_{i,j\ge0} f_{i,j}(Z)X^iY^j,$$

$$(1+X+Y+XY)^Z=\sum_{i,j\ge0}g_{i,j}(Z)X^iY^j.$$

Since $(1+X)^n(1+Y)^n=(1+X+Y+XY)^n$ for all naturals $n\ge0$, we may conclude that the coefficients $f_{ij}(n)=g_{ij}(n)$ agree on infinitely many $n$, hence $f_{i,j}(Z)=g_{i,j}(Z)$.